# How can I do something or call back-end after upload a file

Tags: html, ajax, portlet

I'm trying to allow user upload their excel file, after that back-end will convert it as html format and suppose put it in the iframe src allow user preview in browser.

Now I'm trying to call the get path function for set the iframe src during page ready, but seems not work.

```
    <portlet:actionURL var="checkworkbook" name="checkWorkbook"></portlet:actionURL>
    <b>Please Upload a Document</b> 

     <form name ="UploadExcelForm" action="<%=checkworkbook%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="uploadedFile" name="uploadedFile" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel">
    <button type="button" onclick="<portlet:namespace />uploadExcel()"> submit </button>
    </form>

    <div id="displayArea">
    <iframe id="displayExcel" src="" weight=800 height=400>Please Upload a file</iframe>
    </div>
```

Here is the ajax part

```
 function <portlet:namespace />uploadExcel() {
        if ($('#uploadedFile').val() == null) {
            alert("Please choose a file!");
            return false;
        }else{
        document.UploadExcelForm.submit();
    }
        }

    $(document).ready(function(){
                   <portlet:namespace />getDisplayPath();
        });



function <portlet:namespace />getDisplayPath() {
    var url = '<%=urlForAjax%>';
       /*Make ajax call*/
        $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url,
        data: {
            portletAction : "getDisplayPath"
            },
        success : function(data)
        {   
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(obj.jsonPath !=null){
                var json = JSON.parse(obj.jsonPath);
                $("#displayExcel").attr('src',obj.jsonPath);


            }
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
             /*Write you error-handling logic here*/
        }
  });
}
```

Moreover,I'm trying to use uploadExcel() part to make sure that user have select a file before upload, but it's not work, why?

I've do more testing, found that the problem maybe is getting the JSON, so I paste my back-end code here.

```
if ("getDisplayPath".equalsIgnoreCase(ajaxAction)){
            String jsonPath = this.displayPath;
            JSONObject json = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
            json.put("jsonPath", jsonPath);
            response.getWriter().write(json.toString());

        }
```

Comment: how do you construct your `urlForAjax`?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.  However if you want to see an example of the front end side of a file upload in Liferay you can reference this https://gist.github.com/cmaggiulli/11b0d284e4e3f402907e179d1c261f31